# What is the background music from episode 50 of Hajime no Ippo?

Tags: music, hajime-no-ippo

What is the background music from Hajime no Ippo in Episode 50 from 16:10-16:36?

This is where Ippo is declared winner, if you are looking at different sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Song is called "[Stand Proud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AtIhuKn2No)."

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! If possible, can you add some references or evidence to support your answer? We prefer longer posts with details over single line responses.